# Android, Run application without emulator or any device

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, sdk, runtime

I want to test my app and I don't want to run emulator, unfortunately  Windows 8.1 doesn't recognize my Samsung device. I want eclipse just to build the app's `APK` and I'll test the app by myself by using the file that is created in `bin` directory.

when you don't have any compatible emulator or any connected device, eclipse asks for running new emulator, I don't want see this dialog !

Answer (score 2):

First: Consider fixing the problem with Windows recognizing your phone.

Second: You can use the Android SDK to make an APK - you can then transfer it to the device the way you prefer (download from webserver, e-mail eg.). Alternatively you can use Google Play + the alpha/beta testing feature to roll out tests to your device (+ any other device you want to test on).

Comment: I already use this way, I just want to cancel eclipse asking for emulator.

Comment: Then don't click "Run".

Comment: @user3660237 : What exactly do you think "Run" is going to achieve if you don't have an emulator or connected device? I really don't understand why you're using the "Run" option.

Comment: Because I need the APK and build button doesn't create it !

Answer (score 1):

In that case, Only `Build` the project, then in your project directory look for "bin" folder, you will find an APK file of your project there, you can copy that and install it later on your device

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can get the application in the bin folder there you can find the apk.

You can build by running the command "ant clean release install" from your application folder.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, building the project alone won't create an APK file. You can export your project to get APK file. For exporting, right-click on your project in Eclipse and select **Export...**, then choose **Export Android Application**:

[image: Export Android Application]

Please note that you have to create a key to export your project and sign it. If you want to create an unsigned package (which must be only used for testing purposes), right-click on your project, then from **Android Tools** select **Export Unsigned Application Package**:

[image: Export Unsigned Application Package]

Comment: thanks but I prefer to press that cancel button than this long way :)

Comment: **"Unfortunately, building the project alone won't create an APK file."** : Huh? Where do you get that idea from. A build will produce a debug apk - there's no need to export the application package.

Comment: @squonk , He's right, when u delete the apk from bin directory and use build option alone, it doesn't create the apk

Comment: @user3660237 : No he's not. It seems you have the "Skip packaging and dexing until export or launch" set. My app rebuilds every time I save any changes and creates the apk file every time. Trust me - I've been developing for Android with Eclipse for 3 1/2 years.

Comment: @squonk , you're righttttttttttttttttttttt yohooooooooo

Answer (score -1):

On ecllipse editor try this:

go to  Windows -> Select Preferences

```
then Android -> Build

Now uncheck "Skip packaging and dexing until export or launch. (Speeds up automatic builds on file save.)"
```

You may need to restart ecllipse.